# Spark on yarn runs indefinity

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I had spark (2.2 on hadoop 2.7) jobs running and had to restart the sparkmaster machine. Now the spark jobs on yarn is getting submitted, Accepted and running but does not end.

Cluster ( 1 + 3 nodes). Resourcemanager & Namenode running on sparkmaster node. And Nodemanager and Datanode running on 3 worker nodes.

Executor Log:

```
/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
17/12/15 08:58:02 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Started daemon with process name: 130256@cassandralake1node3.localdomain     
17/12/15 08:58:02 INFO util.SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for TERM    
17/12/15 08:58:02 INFO util.SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for HUP    
17/12/15 08:58:02 INFO util.SignalUtils: Registered signal handler for INT    
17/12/15 08:58:03 WARN util.Utils: Your hostname, cassandralake1node3.localdomain resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 10.204.211.105 instead (on interface em1)
17/12/15 08:58:03 WARN util.Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
17/12/15 08:58:03 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
17/12/15 08:58:03 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
17/12/15 08:58:03 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/12/15 08:58:03 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/12/15 08:58:03 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/12/15 08:58:03 INFO client.TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /10.204.211.105:40866 after 85 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls to: root
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls to: root
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing view acls groups to: 
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO spark.SecurityManager: Changing modify acls groups to: 
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO spark.SecurityManager: SecurityManager: authentication disabled; ui acls disabled; users  with view permissions: Set(root); groups with view permissions: Set(); users  with modify permissions: Set(root); groups with modify permissions: Set()
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO client.TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to /10.204.211.105:40866 after 1 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO storage.DiskBlockManager: Created local directory at /tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1513329182871_0010/blockmgr-15ae52df-c267-427e-b8f1-ef1c84059740
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO memory.MemoryStore: MemoryStore started with capacity 1311.0 MB
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Connecting to driver: spark://CoarseGrainedScheduler@10.204.211.105:40866
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: Successfully registered with driver
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO executor.Executor: Starting executor ID 1 on host cassandranode3
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'org.apache.spark.network.netty.NettyBlockTransferService' on port 35983.
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO netty.NettyBlockTransferService: Server created on cassandranode3:35983
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO storage.BlockManager: Using org.apache.spark.storage.RandomBlockReplicationPolicy for block replication policy
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registering BlockManager BlockManagerId(1, cassandranode3, 35983, None)
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO storage.BlockManagerMaster: Registered BlockManager BlockManagerId(1, cassandranode3, 35983, None)
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO storage.BlockManager: external shuffle service port = 7337
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO storage.BlockManager: Registering executor with local external shuffle service.
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO client.TransportClientFactory: Successfully created connection to cassandranode3/10.204.211.105:7337 after 1 ms (0 ms spent in bootstraps)
17/12/15 08:58:04 INFO storage.BlockManager: Initialized BlockManager: BlockManagerId(1, cassandranode3, 35983, None)
```

Driver Log:

```
O util.Utils: Using initial executors = 2, max of spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors, spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors and spark.executor.instances
17/12/15 09:50:06 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Will request 2 executor container(s), each with 1 core(s) and 3072 MB memory (including 1024 MB of overhead)
17/12/15 09:50:06 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Submitted 2 unlocalized container requests.
17/12/15 09:50:06 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Started progress reporter thread with (heartbeat : 3000, initial allocation : 200) intervals
17/12/15 09:50:07 INFO impl.AMRMClientImpl: Received new token for : cassandranode2:38628
17/12/15 09:50:07 INFO impl.AMRMClientImpl: Received new token for : cassandranode3:39212
17/12/15 09:50:07 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Launching container container_1513329182871_0011_01_000002 on host cassandranode2 for executor with ID 1
17/12/15 09:50:07 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Launching container container_1513329182871_0011_01_000003 on host cassandranode3 for executor with ID 2
17/12/15 09:50:07 INFO yarn.YarnAllocator: Received 2 containers from YARN, launching executors on 2 of them.
17/12/15 09:50:07 INFO impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: yarn.client.max-cached-nodemanagers-proxies : 0
17/12/15 09:50:07 INFO impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: yarn.client.max-cached-nodemanagers-proxies : 0
17/12/15 09:50:07 INFO impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: Opening proxy : cassandranode3:39212
17/12/15 09:50:07 INFO impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy: Opening proxy : cassandranode2:38628
17/12/15 09:50:09 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (10.204.211.105:47622) with ID 2
17/12/15 09:50:09 INFO spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: New executor 2 has registered (new total is 1)
17/12/15 09:50:09 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager cassandranode3:33779 with 1311.0 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(2, cassandranode3, 33779, None)
17/12/15 09:50:11 INFO cluster.YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnDriverEndpoint: Registered executor NettyRpcEndpointRef(spark-client://Executor) (10.204.211.103:43578) with ID 1
17/12/15 09:50:11 INFO spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: New executor 1 has registered (new total is 2)
17/12/15 09:50:11 INFO storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint: Registering block manager cassandranode2:37931 with 1311.0 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, cassandranode2, 37931, None)
17/12/15 09:50:11 INFO cluster.YarnClusterSchedulerBackend: SchedulerBackend is ready for scheduling beginning after reached minRegisteredResourcesRatio: 0.8
17/12/15 09:50:11 INFO cluster.YarnClusterScheduler: YarnClusterScheduler.postStartHook done
17/12/15 09:50:11 INFO internal.SharedState: Setting hive.metastore.warehouse.dir ('null') to the value of spark.sql.warehouse.dir ('file:/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1513329182871_0011/container_1513329182871_0011_01_000001/spark-warehouse').
17/12/15 09:50:11 INFO internal.SharedState: Warehouse path is 'file:/tmp/hadoop-root/nm-local-dir/usercache/root/appcache/application_1513329182871_0011/container_1513329182871_0011_01_000001/spark-warehouse'.
17/12/15 09:50:11 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@e087bd4{/SQL,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
17/12/15 09:50:11 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@c93af1f{/SQL/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
17/12/15 09:50:11 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@53fd3a5d{/SQL/execution,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
17/12/15 09:50:11 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@7dcd6778{/SQL/execution/json,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
17/12/15 09:50:11 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.s.j.s.ServletContextHandler@3a25ecc9{/static/sql,null,AVAILABLE,@Spark}
17/12/15 09:50:12 INFO state.StateStoreCoordinatorRef: Registered StateStoreCoordinator endpoint
17/12/15 09:51:09 INFO spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: Request to remove executorIds: 2
17/12/15 09:51:11 INFO spark.ExecutorAllocationManager: Request to remove executorIds: 1
```

spark-default.conf

```
spark.master                      yarn
spark.eventLog.enabled            true
spark.eventLog.dir                file:///home/sparkeventlogs
spark.serializer                  org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.driver.memory               5g
spark.driver.cores                1
spark.yarn.am.memory              2048m
spark.yarn.am.cores               1
spark.submit.deployMode           cluster
spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled   true
spark.shuffle.service.enabled     true
spark.driver.maxResultSize        20g
spark.jars.packages               datastax:spark-cassandra-connector:2.0.5-s_2.11
spark.cassandra.connection.host   10.204.211.101,10.204.211.103,10.204.211.105
spark.executor.extraJavaOptions   -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps
spark.driver.extraJavaOptions     -Dhdp.version=2.7.4
spark.cassandra.read.timeout_ms   180000
spark.yarn.stagingDir            hdfs:///tmp
spark.network.timeout             2400
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead  2048
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead 1024
spark.network.timeout             2400
yarn.resourcemanager.app.timeout.minutes=-1
spark.yarn.submit.waitAppCompletion true 
spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.compressed true
spark.sql.inMemoryColumnarStorage.batchSize 10000
```

Spark Submit command:

```
spark-submit --class com.swcassandrautil.popstatsclone.popihits --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-cores 1 --executor-memory 2g --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.initialExecutors=2 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors=8 --conf spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=2 --conf spark.memory.fraction=0.75 --conf spark.memory.storageFraction=0.75 /scala/statscloneihits/target/scala-2.11/popstatscloneihits_2.11-1.0.jar "/mnt/data/tmp/xyz*" "\t";
```

Request your input and Appreciate.

Thanks

Comment: Probably not the problem, but `Dhdp.version=2.7.4`? That doesn't exist (yet)... And if you're not using Hortonworks, you don't need that flag... That isn't "Hadoop version"

Comment: In any case, just curious... did Spark work before you added Cassandra?

Comment: Yes. i have good amount of data loaded to Cassandra. I shall remove the Dhdp verison. Had that added recently, with no luck. I meant to configure Hadoop 2.7.4 version

Comment: Spark-shell works currently and i am able to retrieve few rows

Comment: Does `--deploy-mode client` work?

Comment: Dear All,    It was a error in the data when inserting into Cassandra because of null value in key column. It showed the error when i copied the csv source file in local drive.    When the file was in shared drive, it was running for ever without logging this error.    Anyhow no issue with spark config. Thanks All.

Comment: Feel free to answer your question below rather than leave it in the comments